# How to delete value when a Field is unregistred with redux-from

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, redux-form, react-redux-form

I have a question about redux-from.

When I unmount a component, automatically, the action creator unRegistredField is launched. The probleme is that the value is keep in the store.

Do you have an solution to automatically delete value when the Field in unregistred ?

I would not like to launch the action creator by hand!

Comment: How did you declare your Form? With `destroyOnUnmount` set to true (default) field value should be removed from the store...

Comment: `reduxForm( {
  form: 'myForm',
  validate,
  forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
 } ),`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the value with `this.props.change("fieldName", null)`
You can read the doc for this method here: https://redux-form.com/6.2.0/docs/api/props.md/#-change-field-string-value-any-function-

Comment: Yes, for the moment it is my solution but I think is not the better way to do this. I think that is something to add to the decorator reduxFrom(). It not logic to keep the value of the Field is the Field is unregistred...

Answer (score 0):

If someone else comes here looking for a way to remove the  value from the form state (instead of just change the value), you can use `autofill` instead of `change` action, just make sure to set it value to `undefined`.

Like so:

```
// CustomFormContainer.jsx
import {
    reduxForm,
    change,  // Saves the value to the field.
    autofill // Saves the value to the field and sets its autofilled property to true.
} from 'redux-form'

// The presentational component
import CustomForm from './CustomForm.jsx'

const form = 'your-form-name'
const fields = [ 'field-foo', 'field-bar', 'field-baz' ]

const CustomFormContainer = reduxForm({
    form,
    fields
},
/* mapStateToProps = */ undefined,
/* mapDispatchToProps = */ function(dispatch) {
    return {
        // This will be passed as a property to the presentational component
        changeFieldValue: function(field, value) {
            dispatch(autofill(form, field, value))
        }
    }
})(CustomForm)
```

Then, in `./CustomForm.jsx` file, your can do:

`this.props.changeFieldValue('field-baz', undefined)`

Tested with redux form `v8.3.1`